# IE8 loads slow with heavy data, any style is the cause?

Tags: c#, javascript, css, asp.net-mvc

On my webpage, I have a table which is loaded with Razor engine(MVC4 app). When data is small it works fine in all browsers when data exceeds 1000 or 2000 rows it gets horribly slow in IE8 browser and in rest of browsers it works fine (acceptable).

I tried everything (*including the suggestions mentioned in other stackoverflow questions*). My final conclusion was, a particular style on my webpage, is the culprit. Because I stripped everything else from my webpage (javascript, other controls, any imported JS files).

I just wanna know if anyone of you know about any particular style which really slows down IE8 rendering with heavy data.

**EDIT**: *In Short* Performance was acceptable with all styles removed...basically, a simple html table with 2000+ records works smoothly on IE8. but with my styles applied it get slow. So anyone familiar with any particular style which makes IE8 slow?

Comment: Are you saying performance was acceptable with all styles removed? Or that removing all JS but leaving the styles didn't help with performance?

Comment: Yes, performance was acceptable with all styles removed...basically, a simple html table with 2000+ records works smoothly on IE8. but with my styles applied it get slow